# How to increase or scale a monk catfolk's natural attack (Claw) as a monks scaling unarmed strike damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Playing a catfolk monk and have a problem. Cat folk has a natural claw attack of 1d4. Monk has a level scaling unarmed stike of 1d6. Is there a way for the catfolk's claw attack to scale in damage as monks unarmed?

Comment: Related: [Do natural attacks and monks unarmed damage stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78217)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't apply unarmed damage progression to natural attacks.

The [Monastic Legacy](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Monastic%20Legacy) feat could apply damage progression to your natural attacks if you have [Feral Combat Training](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Feral%20Combat%20Training), but it only counts your *non-monk* class levels.

Comment: From what I see of Monastic Legacy, it does absolutely zero to apply monk damage to natural weapons, even with Feral Combat Training. I understand why you might think it does, but Monastic Legacy only increases your effective monk level if you are multiclass.

Comment: @YogoZuno Because Monastic Legacy has Improved Unarmed Strike as a prerequisite, it can be applied to natural attacks with Feral Combat Training. This interaction is definitely unintended and because of this very poorly worded, but it should work by RAW.

Comment: Sure, they can interact, but...Monastic Legacy actually doesn't DO anything that will improve the natural attack. It increases your unarmed strike damage, but never says anything about using unarmed strike damage for a natural weapon. If Monastic Legacy said something like 'improve the damage of any weapon you're using', then sure. But it doesn't.